# Como colocar um módulo Python numa pasta diferente do meu script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando rodar um script em Python (*v2.4 e v2.7*) e criei um módulo com alguns métodos. Infelizmente este módulo precisa ficar numa pasta separada.

Na [**documentação do Python**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) e até aqui no Stack Overflow eu encontrei inúmeros post falando pra adicionar o `__init__.py` em cada pasta do meu projeto.

O meu problema é que o meu script fica numa estrutura e meu módulo fica em outra. Minha situação é esta:

```
pasta1/
   script.py
pasta2/
   modules/
      python/
          pasta3/
              \__init\__.py
               modulo1.py
               modulo2.py
```

A parte que estou chamando estes módulos no meu script é:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys  
import datetime  

from pasta3.modulo1 import Mod1  
from pasta3.modulo2 import Mod2
```

**O erro**:

```
$ ./script.py   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
     File "./script.py", line 9, in <module> from pasta3.modulo1 import Mod1  
ImportError: No module named pasta3.modulo1
```

Não posso usar o `sys.path.append("../modules/python/")` porque no *Python 2.4* ele não é reconhecido.

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: ImportError: No module named pasta3.modulo1, o caminho está errado, o arquivo que está importando está aonde? Esta estrutura está certa?

Comment: Sim, a estrutura está certa. No Python 2.7 eu adicionava o sys.path.append("../modules/python/") e funcionava, mas, este, não foi implementado/funciona no python 2.4

Comment: bred, aqui não usamos "resolvido" no título. Marque uma resposta como correta ou escreva a sua própria explicando a solução. Veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: valeu. Não tinha visto o símbolo pra aceitar a resposta.

Comment: coloca um doc __init__.py dentro de pasta2 em cada uma das subpastas, talvez funcione não tenho certeza, senão vc vai ter que colocar o diretório todo para poder acessar ou abreviar com o ../

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Python *2.x*, você pode usar o módulo [`Imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

> This module provides an interface to the mechanisms used to implement
>   the `import` statement.

Use as funções [`find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) e [`load_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module).

- [`find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module): Vai procurar o módulo pelo nome, se a pesquisa for bem sucedida, o valor de retorno é uma tupla de 3 elementos contendo o arquivo, caminho, e descrição.
- [`load_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module): Vai importar o módulo, se o módulo já tiver sido importado, o mesmo será apenas recarregado - equivalente a função [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload). O retorno é um objeto que aponta para o módulo, caso contrário um exceção [`ImportError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError) é lançada.

Exemplo:

```
import imp

arquivo, caminho, descricao = imp.find_module('Modulo1', ['/foo/bar/baz/'])

modulo1 = imp.load_module('Modulo1', arquivo, caminho, descricao)

modulo1.funcao1()
```

---

A partir da versão *+3.4* do Python o módulo `Imp` tornou-se [obsoleto](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#deprecations-in-the-python-api), como alternativa pode-se usar o módulo [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) (está disponível desde o Python *2.7*).

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Eu só pude testar hoje. Tive que fazer umas poucas alterações no meu código e funcionou muito bem!

Answer (score 4):

Tente retornar um diretório e indicar o caminho.

Exemplo:

**script.py**

```
from ..pasta3.modulo1 import Mod1
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer este funcionar no meu código. Consegui utilizando esta solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14116/8057

Comment: @bred81 o caminho que eu coloquei não está certo, você deveria colocar de acordo com o seu projeto, talvez seja `from ..pasta2.modules.python.pasta3.modulo1 import Mod1`, mas se a resposta de DBX8 resolveu o seu problema, marque a resposta dele como aceita. Abs.

Comment: eu sei que o caminho que você colocou não está certo. Mas também não consegui acertar aqui...

Answer (score 2):

Configure a variável de ambiente `PYTHONPATH` e inclua (`append` se já existir) o diretorio `pasta3`:

```
export PYTHONPATH = /pasta2/modules/python/pasta3
```

Em todo caso, você pode usar o caminho completo para `pasta3` em vez de relativo.

Comment: Esta solução até que funciona, mas não é "elegante".
Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Porque não usar um *symlink* para `pasta2` dentro da `pasta1`:

```
$ ln -s ./pasta2 ./pasta1/pasta2
```

Comment: Era a minha ideia, esta, mas, quanto mais for crescendo, mais terei que adicionar links simbólicos, o que tornaria ineficaz esta prática.